# Wordpress me pide los datos ftp para actualizar los plugins

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp, wordpress-plugin

Desde ayer cada vez que quiero actualizar un plugin, Wordpress me pide los datos ftp, los cuales nunca tuve y nunca puse porque utilizo una instancia ec2 y me conecto al ftp con el archivo PEM. Alguien sabe porque wordpress me pide estos datos que antes no me pedia?. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Eso quiere decir que Wordpress por si solo no esta teniendo permiso para actualizarlos.

O bien la carpeta de los plugins (o sus padres) no tienen permisos de escritura o los directorios y archivos no pertenecen al usuario con que se esta ejecutando Apache (www-data o apache segun el sistema operativo).

Answer (score 1):

La recomendación de WordPress es que tus carpetas tengan permisos 750 (o 755 sólo si hace falta), y los archivos 640 (o 644). Eso permitiría que WordPress actualice tus plugins y archivos.

Para modificar los permisos, podés hacerlo desde el panel de control de tu hosting, o bien usar un programa de FTP como Filezilla, donde podés hacer click derecho sobre el archivo o carpeta y elegir "Cambiar Permisos".